# Can wget convert links within a local html document?

Tags: wget, mirroring

I know that `wget` can fetch a remote page and its dependencies and rewrite the html so that image `src` attributes reference the newly downloaded images.

I am trying to convert local html files that reference images on the Internet.
I'm using

```
wget --mirror --page-requisites --convert-links \
     --directory-prefix=foo \
     --force-html \
     --input-file=my_file.html
```

All of the referenced images are downloaded to the appropriate places in `foo/` but the `src` attributes in `my_file.html` aren't being changed.

Comment: Can't you use regex to fix them?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping that I could use `wget`'s built in functionality, but I ended up replacing the attributes manually.

Comment: This question is NOT a duplicate of the referenced question.  In this question, the OP *is* using `--convert-links` which is a synonym for `-k`.  The referenced question is asking what to do in the event that -k was not used.  This question, on the other hand, is asking how to use the `-k` option with a *local* html file.  I am currently having the same problem.  I am using `-k` and, thanks to the OP's question, I have figured out how to use `--input-file` for a local input.  However, just like the OP, the links in the html file are not being updated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 wget --recursive   --page-requisites --html-extension=on --convert-links="on" --domains="www.thesite.com" --no-parent http://www.thesite.com
```

This will bring you an entire website locally. just tried it, working fine.
with local resources

Comment: I already have the website; the problem was that the links weren't being rewritten. in `my_file.html`

Comment: @Kevin L. Please provide the site url that you want to download. BTW, if the links made in JavaScript, you cant do it with wget. nevetheless, provide the url.

Comment: there is no URL.  It is a local HTML file.